# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when mongod

Tags: ubuntu

when I execute:
./mongod --dbpath=/usr/local/data/mongo_data
the result is :Segmentation fault (core dumped)
hope someone help me,thanks!

Comment: Did you try calling mongod directly?

mongod --dbpath=/usr/local/data/mongo_data

Comment: you mean mongod --dbpath=/usr/local/data/mongo_data?yes ,i tried ,but i didnt work, but i try to execute:  ./bin/ mongod --dbpath=/usr/local/data/mongo_data,it works,do you know why?i  use the ubuntu 18.10,but thank you so much for my first question，how do i follow you?

Comment: I tried your code by installing mongodb server on my ububtu 18 and the code worked. If you just started, I recommend to uninstall the current version and reinstall the mongodb server. Just a suggestion. 

Comment: ok, thank you, you are a really nice person.

Answer (score 0):

@zhaoyongxin this steps will guide you 
   **uninstall apt-get remove or purge command from terminals**

```
1) navigate to the mongodb folder that has been downloaded for mongodb site
eg cd mongodb/bin/ 

2) create folder name mongodb-data or any other name like mkdir mongodb-data  

3) ./mongod --dbpath ~/mongodb-data/
```

./mongod will store all your schema in your mongodb-data